# How to check if repository mirror is up to date in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to use repository mirroring to streamline my workflow.
I have a repository that uses pull mirroring from the upstream.
I am trying to [trigger mirror update via api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html#trigger-update-using-api-starter)

My questions:

- Can I find out that the mirror update I triggered if finished?
- Alternatively, can I find out if the mirror (or a particular branch on a mirror) is up-to-date with the upstream?

To give you more context, I want to:

- refresh the mirror
- create a branch on the mirror
- create a merge request to the upstream

I refresh the mirror to ensure that the merge request can be merged without conflicts. My pipeline is the only source of merge requests to the upstream. I am afraid of race condition between refresh mirror request and create branch request.

Comment: Normally you would make changes and MRs to the upstream, because it's recommended not to work off of the mirror. Is there a reason why you're not doing all the work on the upstream?
Also, are you trying to find out if the mirror updated via API? It definitely displays in the UI when it was last updated

Answer (score 1):

There are two fields ton the [get single project endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project) `GET /projects/:id`

- import_status (with "finished" as a marker of success)
- import_error (with null as a marker of success)

I wasn't able to find out the timestamp of last mirror update though.